# Command not found - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-decorators

I'm trying to create a bot with the help of Python and the discord.py library.

I have two files main.py, and MyBot.py.

**Main.py**

```py
from MyBot import MyBot

bot = MyBot()
bot.run("API_KEY")
```

**MyBot.py**

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import command


class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix="!")

    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Bot ready.")

    @command(name="hello", help="Say hello")
    async def hello(ctx, arg):
        await ctx.channel.send("Hello you!")
```

When running the command `!hello` I get an exception in my script

```
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "hello" is not found
```

I think the error comes from the way I use the decorator, but I have no idea how to fix it.
Please note that I'm currently learning python co-routines & decorators. So this is a new notion to me.

Anyway, thanks a lot to anyone willing to help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to inherit from commands.Bot use:

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import command

class MyBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix="!")

    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Bot ready.")


bot = MyBot()

@bot.command(name="hello", help="Say hello")
async def hello(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.channel.send("Hello you!")

bot.run('token')
```

If you are inheriting from MyBot as a method to group commands use [cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html#cogs). In its current state, inheriting from commands.Bot has no practical usage.